# Encoding/decoding works in browser, but not in terminal

Tags: python, encoding, urllib

Here's my code:

```
import urllib

print urllib.urlopen('http://www.indianexpress.com/news/heart-of-the-deal/811626/').read().decode('iso-8859-1')
```

When I view the page in Firefox, the text is displayed correctly. However, on the terminal, I see issues with character encoding.

Here are some malformed output examples:

```
long-term  in
Indias
no-go areas
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: it could be just your terminal couldn't display certain character sets. *.decode('iso-8859-1') will give you an unicode object, but it doesn't make sure that your terminal could display it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this (ignore unknown chars)

```
import urllib
url = 'http://www.indianexpress.com/news/heart-of-the-deal/811626/'
print urllib.urlopen(url).read().decode('iso-8859-1').encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the actual charset [sent by the server](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset) instead of always assuming it's ISO 8859-1. Using a capable HTML parser such as [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) can help.

Comment: I wasn't assuming ISO 8859-1. The encoding is specified in the meta tags of the returned HTML document.

Comment: I use lxml.html to parse the HTML.

Comment: Then why are you decoding it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The web-page lies; it is encoded in `cp1252` aka `windows-1252`, NOT in ISO-8859-1.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> guff = urllib.urlopen('http://www.indianexpress.com/news/heart-of-the-deal/811626/').read()
>>> uguff = guff.decode('latin1')
>>> baddies = set(c for c in uguff if u'\x80' <= c < u'\xa0')
>>> baddies
set([u'\x93', u'\x92', u'\x94', u'\x97'])
```